# Search Screen with Python

Tags: python, bots

I'm working on making a "bot" for a game I play on my computer (windows8.1) just to see if I can. One of the tasks I need to automate is to find something on the screen. I can't get the sprites for the game though. I tried taking a screenshot and searching the screen for that image but it fails because the exact image is not on the screen. I imagine I would need to check pixels (if that's possible)

I'm not looking for actual code as an answer. I just need somewhere I can learn how to do what I want to do. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making "bots" like you do, your approach of searching for pixels is usually a bad practice. It's really error-prone and needs a ton of computing power.
Other popular tools (for example the hearthstone deck tracker) are checking the ram for the current state of the game. This is the safest and best approach. 
Python is probably not capable doing that.

Java, C++ or C# are the language you want to write a bot in. I'd highly recommend you switch to one of these.
The Hearthstone Deck Tracker is an open source project on github. Check the code if you want to learn something about bots / tools https://github.com/Epix37/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker.

Comment: I understand it's not really the best way to do it. I'm just curious if there is a way to do it. It doesn't necessarily have to be done via pixel comparison. I'm just curious if it can be done and if so, how?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my post. Checking the memory variables is the normal approach.